# How to make a random video play on a page without repeating?

Tags: random, video

In a web browser with vanilla javascript, I already made the video randomly play. I have a list of 6 videos, I want each video in the list to play randomly and not repeat until the list of 6 videos ends and then start over again.
Here is the code:

```js
function refreshbutton(){
var count = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length);
document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].src = "./videos/" + videos[count];video.load();}
var videos= ["video1.mp4","video2.mp4","video3.mp4"];
```

```
<i onclick="refreshbutton();" class="brefreshbutton fa fa-refresh fa-spin" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" title="Watch another video"></i>

<div class="video-fallback"></div>
<video id="video" onloadstart="this.volume=0.6" loop="" autoplay="">
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var videos2 = [
  'video4.mp4',
  'video5.mp4',
  'video6.mp4'
  ];
  var count = Math.floor(Math.random() * videos2.length);
  document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].src = './videos/' + videos2[count];
  </script>
</video>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML code? 
Pay attention to remove "loop" from the "video" tag.

Comment: @OOM i just added

Comment: @MapKicc I assume your _"not repeat"_ means **not selecting the same item twice** from the Array? If yes, consider keeping the _"played"_ video names in another Array. Whenever `refreshbutton` is clicked, you get a video name using `videos[count]` then use a **For loop** to check if same exists in the "alreadyPlayedVideos" array. If it exists (is going to repeat) you simply tell the function `refreshbutton();` to run again to get a new count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever **refreshbutton** is clicked, you get a video name using `videos[count]` then use a **FOR** loop to check if same video URL exists in the "alreadyPlayedVideos" array. 
If it exists (will repeat) you simply run again the function `refreshbutton();` to get a new count.

Untested code but the logic is there to learn from:

```
<i onclick="refreshbutton()" class="brefreshbutton fa fa-refresh fa-spin" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" title="Watch another video"></i>

<div class="video-fallback">

    <video id="video" onloadstart="this.volume=0.6" loop="" autoplay="">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var videos = ["video1.mp4", "video2.mp4", "video3.mp4", 'video4.mp4', 'video5.mp4', 'video6.mp4'];
var videosPlayed = [];
var count = 0; 
var count_prev = 0;
var count_playlist = 0;

var myVid = document.getElementById("video");

//# loading first video
refreshbutton();

function getRandomVideoNum()
{
    count = Math.floor( Math.random() * videos.length );
    
    //# checking for sequential duplicate values...
    if( count == count_prev ) { getRandomVideoNum(); }
    
    //# checking if "Played" list has ended, then reset that list with new random videos
    if( videosPlayed.length == videos.length)
    { console.log( "### full playlist... doing reset"); videosPlayed.length = 0; getRandomVideoNum(); }
    
    //# check if already played...
    for(var i=0; i < (videosPlayed.length-1); i++)
    {
        //# has been already played so re-run function for a new "count" value
        if( videosPlayed[i] == videos[count] ) { getRandomVideoNum(); }
    }
    
    count_prev = count; //# update for top checking of duplicate values
}

function refreshbutton()
{
    getRandomVideoNum(); //# get a new "count" value

    //# update the "already played" list
    videosPlayed[ (videosPlayed.length) ] = videos[count];
    
    //# set "src" then "load" to ready video for "play" command
    myVid.src = "./video/" + videos[count];
    myVid.load(); myVid.play();
    
    /*
    //# if you want feedback / logging
    if( videosPlayed.length == videos.length )
    {
        count_playlist++; //# add +1 to "just played" playlist number 
        
        console.log( 
        "## ==================================" +
        "\n" + ">> Playlist num : " + count_playlist +
        "\n" + ">> videos.length : " + videos.length +
        "\n" + ">> the items were : " +
        "\n" + "vidplayed 0 : " + videosPlayed[0] +
        "\n" + "vidplayed 1 : " + videosPlayed[1] +
        "\n" + "vidplayed 2 : " + videosPlayed[2] +
        "\n" + "vidplayed 3 : " + videosPlayed[3] +
        "\n" + "vidplayed 4 : " + videosPlayed[4] +
        "\n" + "vidplayed 5 : " + videosPlayed[5] +
        "\n" + "===================================="
        );
    }
    */

}

</script>
```

##### Update:

**Regarding using one of first two videos**...

> *"How can I make it so that when the "refreshbutton" button is first time pressed, there is a choice between only the first two videos in the "videos" list?"*

**(1)** Create a variable to note if it's the first time playing the video.

```
var isFirstPlay = true;
```

**(2)** Select a random number between 0 and 1 (I use 1.2 as maximum to help against the bias of too many "zero" results) then use that video, also turning off (false) the "first time playing" boolean.

Add an `If` statement at top, to handle choosing an Array position (where `count` is `0` or `1`).

```
function getRandomVideoNum()
{
    if ( isFirstPlay == true )
    {
        alert( "is first play");
        count = Math.round( Math.random() * 1.2 );
        count_prev = count;
        isFirstPlay = false;
        return;
    }
    
    //... rest of code 
    
    count = Math.floor( Math.random() * videos.length );
    
    //# checking for sequential duplicate values...
    if( count == count_prev ) { getRandomVideoNum(); }
    
    //.. etc etc...
    
}
```

Comment: I added your code but it doesn't work, the videos plays but still repeating

Comment: It is repeating, but now it can repeats only be through one video. That is, it does not repeat in a row, but I need this video not to repeat until the entire circle of 6 videos has been completed

Comment: I have a list of 6 videos, I want each video in the list to play randomly and not repeat until the list of 6 videos ends and then start over again

Comment: Your code is working, I didn't explain it well, sorry

Comment: So do you know how to do that?

Comment: No worries. See if the updated code is closer to what you need...? Let me know if it works.

Comment: How can I make it so that when the "refreshbutton" button is first time pressed, there is a choice between only the first two videos in the "videos" list?

Comment: See if the new update helps you.